# line width is increasing on button click and decreasing as well but it is not showing the decreased line on linedecr button click

Tags: android, android-widget

here is my code for mainactivity: ResizeLineActivity.java
in which i can increase the line width on lineincr button click and line width is decreasing on linedecr button click but the problem is the decreased line width is only get displayed on lineincr button clik. I don't understand what is wrong in the code. Cab anybody explain or correct this code to show decreased line on linedecr button click?

```
package edu.interview;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ResizeLineActivity extends Activity {
DrawLine drawLine;
Button Lineincr;
Button linedecr;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
int i=0;
static float x1=50;
static float y1=100;
static float x2=90;
static float y2=100;
static int temp=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Lineincr =(Button)(findViewById(R.id.btn_incr));
    linedecr= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_decr);
    final LinearLayout linearltdrawLine=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_showLineView);
//  linearltdrawLine.addView(new DrawLine(this, 50, 100, 100, 100));
    Lineincr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //  temp=++i;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            linearltdrawLine.removeAllViews();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello Line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            linearltdrawLine.addView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(), x1, y1, x2, y2));
            int width1=linearltdrawLine.getWidth();
            /*  TextView txtv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_showLineView);
            txtv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            txtv.setText("Insteas of line");*/
            linearltdrawLine.invalidate();
            linearltdrawLine.refreshDrawableState();
        //  linearltdrawLine.addView(txtv,layoutParams);
            linearltdrawLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //linearltdrawLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //  linearltdrawLine.invalidate();
        //  linearltdrawLine.removeView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(), x1, y1, x2, y2));
            for(i=0;i<=1;++i){
                x2=x2+1;
                linearltdrawLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearltdrawLine.addView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(), x1, y1, x2, y2));
            //  linearltdrawLine.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        }
    });


    linedecr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Line is decreasing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            linearltdrawLine.addView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(), x1, y1, x2, y2));
            linearltdrawLine.invalidate();

            linearltdrawLine.refreshDrawableState();
            //linearltdrawLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for(i=1;i>0;i--){
                linearltdrawLine.removeView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(),x1,y1,x2,y2));
                x2=x2-1;
                linearltdrawLine.invalidate();
                linearltdrawLine.addView(new DrawLine(getApplicationContext(), x1, y1, x2, y2));
                linearltdrawLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

DrawLine.java

```
package edu.interview;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class DrawLine extends View{
private final float X1,Y1,X2,Y2;
private final Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
public DrawLine(Context context,float x1,float y1,float x2, float y2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated consructor stub
    super(context);
    this.X1=x1;
    this.Y1=y1;
    this.X2=x2;
    this.Y2=y2;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, paint);
}
```

}

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#BEE40F" >
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearlayout_showLineView" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.81" android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout_showtxt" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="0.26"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_weight="0.06">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_incr"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Line++"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="106dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
         >
    </Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_decr"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Line --" 
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_decr" android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: got the answer for re-sizable line- In above code ResizeLineActivity.java in linedecr button click's onClick method modify the for loop as for(int i=0;i<1;i++){x2=x2-1;}

Comment: the same logic can be implemented for re-sizable Circle.